# Cannot reference .py file in Google Drive even though everything is mounted correctly

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to access a function in a .py file from Google Drive through Google Colab. I've done all of the mounting and pathing correctly, as far as I'm aware, yet it is still not recognizing the file. I've attached screenshots of the entire notebook. It's currently pretty small.

[image: Image of Notebook]

[image: Image of Error]

I'm not sure why the first code block is labeled as '[7]', because it is the very first one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have the __init__.py file in tests folder in google drive?

Comment: Looks like the existing `IPython/extensions/tests` is interfering. It might be easiest to rename your module, or put it in a folder and do `from foo.tests import ...`

Answer (score 5):

I tried to reproduce the issue now by create a package and test to load it. Then remove the `__init__.py` and got the same error message as you.

```
% touch __init__.py
% cd ..
% python
>>> from tests import t6
>>> dir(t6)
[... 'add_one']
>>> ^D
% rm tests/__init__.py 
% python              
>>> from tests import t6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 't6' from 'tests' (......python3.8/site-packages/tests/__init__.py)
```

```
root
 └── tests/
     ├── __init__.py
     └── t6.py
```

In t6.py I had the function

```
def add_one(number):
    return number + 1
```

You can read more about packages here:
https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

It could also be that you have conflicting package names, since tests is not so unique name. It might be good to keep your own project files under company name or your own name in he package as suggested in link above.

Edit:

Test to run these commands:

```
>>> import tests
>>> tests.__path__
```

I suspect that you have another package called tests in your path.

To fix it I guess it should be easiest to rename the folder to more unique.

EDIT 2:
Run these command to see what your path points to. Add your google drive first in the path.

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Comment: i appreciate the help! I checked out the link you sent and it did a good job of explaining. For some reason I am still getting an error. I added an empty "__init__.py" file to where tests.py is contained, yet it did not solve the problem. Odd.

Comment: I added an edit in the end if the Answer. Hope that will give more clue why its not working.

Comment: @OMeihls this answer covers the case where `tests` is a folder and `t6.py` is a module in that folder. Whereas in your case, it looks like `tests.py` is a module and `t6()` is a function within it?

Comment: @slothrop, yes that is correct. tests.py is the module and t6() is a function inside of it. There are many functions within it and its for an assignment for a class. None of the functions are working and all have the same issue.

Comment: Did you try to run the commands in the end of my answer under Edit? I suspect that you have wrong tests.py imported. That it don´t point your google drive. What do you have in your pythonpath?